# i have a problem in HTML & JavaScript when press button won,t open .. Thanks

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://jsbin.com/haluhifuqe/edit?html,js,output
i have a problem in HTML & JavaScript when press button won't open .. help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <p id="paragraphText">This is awesome </p>

  <button oneclick="changeTheText()">Change The text</button>

  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not `oneclick` its `onclick`

Answer (score 2):

```
<button onclick="changeTheText()">Change The text</button>
```

Its onclick not oneclick